# Migration in SQLite MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, maui

I have a .NET MAUI project with SQLite database. I need to add migration for database but get "Add migration" command errors:

```
The specified deps.json [bin\Debug\net8.0-android\ToDoList.deps.json] does not exist.
```

I tried adding `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: are you already using EF?  Sqlite itself doesn't support migrations

Comment: Yes I am using EF.

Answer (score 1):

There is a known issue:[Error "The specified deps.json ... does not exist"](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/28335).

According to the comments:

> his issue is still not solved with the Latest VS 17.9 Preview 1 and also .NET 8 in combination with .NET MAUI

So you can comment to reopen it or post a new issue on the repo.